# How create oracle type object in tibero database

Tags: oracle, plsql, tibero

How in tibero databse create type object, here code of oracle

```
Create or Replace Type tst_type As Object(
param1 VarChar2(4000),
param2    VarChar2(10),

Static Function statfunc1 ( sctx In Out tst_type ) Return Number,
Member Function memberfunc1 ( Self In Out tst_type,
    value In tst_func ) Return Number);
```

?

Comment: Per the Wikipedia entry for Tibero (which reads like an advertisement) Tibero is "...considered an alternative to Oracle Databases due to its complete compatibility with Oracle products, including SQL". I guess this means that "CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE" should work the same as in Oracle. If it doesn't I suggest you contact Tibero support. Best of luck.

Comment: Just like that "CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE" it is don't work
"create or replace TYPE tst_type AS TABLE OF integer;
TBR-7001: General syntax error."

Comment: It certainly appears to me that Tibero doesn't understand "CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE". Since I had to create the [tibero] tag earlier it appears that this is not a mainstream product. I'd guess there aren't many (any?) people on StackOverflow who know anything about Tibero. I think your best bet is to [contact Tibero support](http://m.tmaxsoft.com/en/bbs.do?cms_cd=MSUP_511) for help or [enter a support question for Tibero](https://us.tmaxsoft.com/support/submitIssue.do). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax works fine in Tibero 6.

```
tbSQL 6  

TmaxData Corporation Copyright (c) 2008-. All rights reserved.

Connected to Tibero.
SQL> ed
Wrote file .tbedit.sql

   1 Create or Replace Type tst_type As Object(
   2    param1 VarChar2(4000),
   3    param2 VarChar2(10),
   4    Static Function statfunc1 ( sctx In Out tst_type ) Return Number,
   5    Member Function memberfunc1 ( Self In Out tst_type, value In tst_type ) Return Number);
SQL> /

Type 'TST_TYPE' created.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).